# Regular expression for a path containing a file name with at least one non-numeric character

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have some files

```
\\foo\bar\12345.xml
\\foo\bar\23456.xml
\\foo\bar\12hellothere.xml
\\foo\bar\34youpeople.xml
```

The first two are characterised by only having numbers in the file name (not including the extension). The last two do not consist entirely of numbers.

The directory names *can* contain whitespace and numbers.

Does anyone have a regular expression which matches the *last* two files, and **not** the first two?

I'm implementing this in Java if that is at all relevant.

Essentially I think it boils down to not `.*\\\d+.xml` but I don't know how to specify the *not*.

Comment: Simplest (?): `[a-zA-Z][^\\]*\.xml` - make sure there is an alpha character after the last `\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

`^((?!(.*\\\d+.xml)).)*$`

is one way.

Inspired from [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Answer (score 0):

Only for file name:
[0-9][0-9][a-z]+

File name + .xml:
[0-9][0-9][a-z]+.xml

Fie name but with more than two numbers on the beginning:
[0-9]+[a-z]+

There is a site where you can test your regular expressions here:
[regexp](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The best regular expression for that would probably be:

(only for filename, for clarity)

> \w*\D\w*.xml

**NOTE:** This considering you consider anything that's not a number as valid, like `10 10.xml`

**EDIT:** In case you want it to be a letter:

> \w*[a-zA-Z]\w*.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String[] s = {
        "\\\\foo\\bar\\12345.xml",
        "\\\\foo\\bar\\23456.xml",
        "\\\\foo\\bar\\12hellothere.xml",
        "\\\\foo\\bar\\34youpeople.xml",
        "34youpeople.xml",
    };
    for (String e : s)
        System.out.println(e + " -> " + e.matches("(.*\\\\)?\\d+[a-zA-Z]+\\.xml"));
```

result:

```
\\foo\bar\12345.xml -> false
\\foo\bar\23456.xml -> false
\\foo\bar\12hellothere.xml -> true
\\foo\bar\34youpeople.xml -> true
34youpeople.xml -> true
```